# JOin the table in Query vs Lazy hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have disabled the Lazy fetching, and i joined the table in Criteria query. But after execution when i try to get the results, it is throwing error as lazy initialization is not done.

How do i resolve this issue?

```
public static String LST_LINEITEM_ANNUAL_ATT = "contractLineItem.lineitemAnnualAtt";
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="LINEITEM_ID",insertable=false,updatable=false)
    private Set<PLineitemAnnualAtt> lineitemAnnualAtt;
```

Criteria Query

```
List lstLineitemSublock = null;
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(PContractLineitem.class, PContractLineitem.CLASS_ALAIS_NAME)
                //.createAlias(PContractLineitem.LST_LINEITEM_SUBBLOCK, PLineitemSubblock.CLASS_ALAIS_NAME)
                .createAlias(PContractLineitem.LST_LINEITEM_ANNUAL_ATT, PLineitemAnnualAtt.CLASS_ALAIS_NAME)
                ;
        this.setAttribute(criteria, restrictions);
        criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
        lstLineitemSublock = criteria.list();
```

Comment: Can you post your Criteria query and stacktrace as well.

Comment: Can you try adding a join to the  `createAlias(PContractLineitem.LST_LINEITEM_ANNUAL_ATT, PLineitemAnnualAtt.CLASS_ALAIS_NAME)` as `createAlias(PContractLineitem.LST_LINEITEM_ANNUAL_ATT, PLineitemAnnualAtt.CLASS_ALAIS_NAME, JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)`

Comment: this is crazy.. it worked..

Comment: how come, i was trying to join with inner join but not working. Why is it so?

Comment: After doing some research, I have found INNER JOIN doesn't populate the collection `lineitemAnnualAtt` and so it is lazily loaded. But with OUTER JOIN it populates the collection `lineitemAnnualAtt`. I have added this to my answer, along with the link see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider specifying `JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN` in the `createAlias` method.

Changing `createAlias(PContractLineitem.LST_LINEITEM_ANNUAL_ATT, PLineitemAnnualAtt.CLASS_ALAIS_NAME)` to `createAlias(PContractLineitem.LST_LINEITEM_ANNUAL_ATT, PLineitemAnnualAtt.CLASS_ALAIS_NAME, JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)` should help.

Regarding why it was not working with INNER JOIN, after doing some research I found this http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/35460-hibernate-createcriteria-question satisfactory.

That says:

When using an alias -defaulting to an inner join- the parent entity that the call returns has the joined collection uninitialized. Hibernate obviously discards the columns related to the collection data and when trying to access the collection another select occurs, generated by the mapping metadata, so it fetches the whole collection.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can chage this:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
```

to:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
```

Also you can hack that, creating another criteria that return lineitemAnnualAtt list and set that to the Object you are returning on you original criteria.